# Backbone Collection.reset() doesn't work on extended Collections

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

I have a Backbone collection

```
jQuery ->
  class App.Collections.List extends Backbone.Collection
    model: App.Models.ListItem
```

I am trying to initialize the collection on page load:

```
var list = new App.Collections.List;
list.reset(<%= @data.to_json.html_safe %>)
```

This throws a JS error in the backbone lib.

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function application.js:597
f.extend._prepareModel application.js:597
f.extend.add application.js:591
f.extend.reset application.js:595
(anonymous function)
```

However, if i change the code to:

```
var list = new Backbone.Collections;
list.reset(<%= @data.to_json.html_safe %>)
```

The reset works, and the collection is populated -- thought the objects in the Collection don't appear to know that they should be ListItem objects. Do I have to do something special to all a reset of my custom Collection?

Comment: Works for me, as far as I can reproduce your setup : http://jsfiddle.net/LXW6h/

Comment: The Model and Collection load order was incorrect. See Derick's answer below and my followup comment to hom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the `_prepareModel` stacktrace line gives a hint that you have your model declared after your collection.

You most likely have your code set up like this:

```
  class App.Collections.List extends Backbone.Collection
    model: App.Models.ListItem

  class App.Models.ListItem extends Backbone.Model
```

which is going to fail because `ListItem` is not yet declared when you try to use it in your collection's `model` attribute. You are essentially setting the model attribute to `undefined`.

You need to declare the model first:

```
  class App.Models.ListItem extends Backbone.Model

  class App.Collections.List extends Backbone.Collection
    model: App.Models.ListItem
```

Note that this is not a limitation in CoffeeScript or Backbone. This is a JavaScript behavior caused by the use of object literals. The value of an object literal key/value pair is evaluated immediately, which means it must exist or it will be returned as undefined or some other error thrown.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. I had put Collections above the Collections above Models because Im trying to model a nested list, so my ListItem Model has a property "children" which was a App.Collections.List ... I assume using a relational Backbone module will be my best best for achieving this?

Comment: Backbone might let you specify a function as the `model` attribute... `App.Collections.List = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: function(){ return MyModelType; });` this would not be subject to the same limitation, as the function will be executed at runtime, when accessing the `model` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As Derick said you need to declare models first, for that purpose just I usually just change require order the App.coffee(main backbone file) to this

```
...
require_tree ./models
require_tree ./collections
...
```